# Grabbing local hostname and creating link with images Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an image link based on the location of the server it is hosted on. If the server is server1. I want the image to be linked to http://server1/dod" I'm trying to get two images with this shot. However, nothing is loading. I am missing a piece and I don't know where. I'm also hosting this on an IIS server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <body>
          <div>
             <p id="Images"></p>
          </div>

          <script>
               var local = location.hostname;

//SP Edit, save a reference to the images node
               var Images = document.getElementById("Images");

               var dodlink = document.createElement(a);
               dodlink.href = "http://" + local + "/DoD/";

               var dodimg = document.createElement("img");
//SP Edit      dodimg.src ="DOD.png";
//SP Edit      dodimg.width = 256;
//SP Edit      dodimg.height = 256;
               dodimg.setAttribute("src", "DOD.png");
               dodimg.setAttribute("width", "256px");
               dodimg.setAttribute("height", "256px");
               dodlink.appendChild(dodimg);

//SP Edit document.getElementByID("Images").innerHTML = dodimg;
               Images.appendChild(dodimg);

               var derlink = document.createElement(a);
//SP Edit      derlink.href = "http://" + local + "/DER/";
               deflink.setAttribute("href", "http://" + local + "/DER/");

               var derimg = document.createElement("img");
//SP Edit      derimg.src ="DER.png";
//SP Edit      derimg.width = 256;
//SP Edit      derimg.height = 256;
               derimg.setAttribute("src", "DER.png");
               derimg.setAttribute("width", "256px");
               derimg.setAttribute("height", "256px");
               deflink.appendChild(derimg);
```

//
                   Images.appendChild(deflink);

Comment: `getElementByID` <-- wrong, use your developer console!

Comment: Setting the innerHTML is going wipe what is in there. So still not going to work when you fix your typo.

Comment: `document.createElement(a)` is also going to throw errors (the a should be in quotes.)    Are you watching the console?  You have quite a few bugs and typos in here which would become immediately apparent if you look at the error messages.

Comment: You can't append elements using innerHTML, this is for adding text, change innerHTML to appendChild and then use derimg as the parameter.  Infact change all your innerHTML references to appendChild(node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var local = location.hostname;

var dodlink = document.createElement('a');
dodlink.href = "http://" + local + "/DoD/";

var dodimg = document.createElement("img");
dodimg.setAttribute("src", "DOD.png");
dodimg.setAttribute("width", "256");
dodimg.setAttribute("height", "256"); 
dodlink.appendChild(dodimg);

document.getElementById("Images").appendChild(dodlink);

var derlink = document.createElement('a');
derlink.href = "http://" + local + "/DER/";

var derimg = document.createElement("img");
derimg.setAttribute("src", "DER.png");
derimg.setAttribute("width", "256");
derimg.setAttribute("height", "256"); 
derlink.appendChild(derimg);

document.getElementById("Images").appendChild(derlink);
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-different than an answer. What did you change? Why should it solve the problem?

Comment: This works perfectly and it is simple to follow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The image sizes are wrong. You need to specify the type eg

```
derimg.width = "256px";
```

instead of

```
derimg.width = 256;
```

also you are changing the

"innerHtml", which is wrong. You need to change the src of an IMG tag and then append it to the "innerHtml".

Also what value is 'a'? Since you've included a whole page I can't see 'a' defined.